# Anime with a young biker boy encountering a girl ghost on an island and having to fulfill a promise he made tp her

Tags: story-identification, anime

What I remember is a guy and girls riding bike in the mountains, they end up starting trouble with a biker gang.  Then the boy sees a girl wandering on an island, she's a ghost, and I think he had promised her something once so he must complete his promise to her.

It's somewhat old, and I think this plot was the series' OVA.

Comment: Do you know the country of origin for the anime? Any descriptions of characters? Any other details that might help somebody identify it?

Comment: specifically how long ago did you watch it?

Answer (score 1):

Could this be [*Idaten Jump*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idaten_Jump) (2005)? It tells the story of a boy and his two friends (boy and a girl) riding their mountain bike and coming across Team Shark Tooth when they get sent to another world and they have to win races to return home.